# How to get Multiple Check box value In Single Column

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

```
<div>
<input style="margin: 14px 0px 0px 0px;" type="checkbox" 
  value="<?php echo $row['Code']; ?>" name="Inc_Rc_Human_Factor" 
  id="Inc_Rc_Human_Factor" onclick="popup(this)" /> 
    <?php echo $row['Description'] ?>
</div>
```

I need to store multiple check box values in a single column in a MySQL DB. Is it possible to store multiple values in a single column? If yes, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `implode()` (you could implode with a comma, for instance) or `serialize()` will retain the array structure.

Comment: Describe it Proper. like what you want? Lots of check boxes in single column with dynamic values

Comment: write your code here so that we can guide you.

Comment: Try saving the values in an array. You could json encode the array and store it in a single column. Later u could decode it and use

Comment: where to use implode(),serialize() is there any sample code.@Rasclatt

Comment: yes you are correct. please guide me @PranavShah

Comment: Lots of check boxes in single column with dynamic values how to store single column in mysql @ApulGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am totally agree with @mmgross.

However, if you want to do this intentionally, try this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27579155/2004910

Comment: yes, so you can keep all values in an array & then use `json_encode` to convert that array into string, then save that. simple!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but what you're trying to do violates 1NF (First normal form) or 2NF (Second normal form), depending on the implementation.

While adhering to the NFs is not an absolute law, violating them without good reason and much though is usually a red flag, that you'll run into trouble at some point later.

I'd suggest to rethink the structure of your database.

Comment: I need lots of check boxes in single column with dynamic values to store single column in MySQL